# Find consecutive or repeating items in list

Tags: python

I have the following python list

`data = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]`

Now I want to partition it so that the consecutive or repeating items are in the same group.

So this should break into two lists as:

`[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4] and [7, 8]`

Tried itertools and group by but had issue with repeating numbers.

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda ix: ix[1] - ix[0] <=1):
    print(list(map(itemgetter(1), g)))
```

Comment: The output of your code snippet appears to work for your example input – could you elaborate on the issue that you've encountered?

Comment: This is not really what `itertools` is good for.  You're going to have to iterate through the list and build the partial sublists yourself.  You should probably do the rest of your homework yourself.

Comment: Sorry had another 2 in my test case and now it returns the whole list.

Comment: It’s not a homework.

Comment: What's the real world use case for this?

Comment: Biological sequence ligament between databases

Comment: the grouping function in itertools only gives you one element, not a pair to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: more-itertools

Its [split_when](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_when) gives you two neighbor elements to decide whether to split between them.

```
from more_itertools import split_when

data = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]

print(*split_when(data, lambda x, y: not x <= y <= x+1))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4] [7, 8]
```

#### Solution 2: nested groupbys

Using one groupby to group repeated elements and then another to group (and chain) consecutive groups:

```py
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]

for _, G in groupby(enumerate(groupby(data)), lambda x: x[0] - x[1][0]):
    print([x for _, (_, g) in G for x in g])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BCoMwEEX3OcVfGohQ20JF6NpDSCgRow2oCekIepZu3LQ36GF6m6o1wwwzfJg3859vN9Hd9vP8GqiO0--n9raDIe3J2vYB0znrCY23gysnxipFClcUicAx5EngLHARSCVjtfW4CeQwfdiKdD902ivSUVBWDOcCrerKSmHMMBYHiXhpiVwmnjEs4bzpKSpG7NRoqYav6HyTxu2K5P_ndw_Byw8)):

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you seek by iterating over the items in your list without the need for additional libraries.

```py
data_in = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
prior = data_in[0]
data_out = [[prior]]
for item in data_in[1:]:
    if item in [prior, prior+1]:
        data_out[-1].append(item)
    else:
        data_out.append([item])
    prior = item

print(data_out)
```

That will give you:

```
[
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    [7, 8]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your really trying to find minimalist code,  You could do something like this:

```
mylist = [1,23,2,2,3,4,7,8,9,11,12,13,20,21,22]
listlist = []
mylist.sort()
sub_list = [mylist[0]]
for i,num in enumerate(mylist[1:]):
    print(num, i)
    if num - mylist[i] == 1:
        sub_list.append(num)
    else:
        listlist.append(sub_list)
        sub_list = [num]
listlist.append(sub_list)
for sub_l in listlist:
    print(sub_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple approach with comprehensions:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

data_in = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]

indices = (index for index, (a, b) in enumerate(pairwise(data_in), 1) if b > a + 1)

data_out = [data_in[a:b] for a, b in pairwise((None, *indices, None))]

>>> [[1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8]]
```

With the benefit of constructing the final result as slices, rather than appending each element.